# Compile openlayer3

Tags: javascript, compilation, openlayers-3

i search a way for extend the OpenLayers.layer.markers class.

Actualy i try to compile myself openlayer3.
the "build.py" script create  "ol.js" file.

but if i replace `<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>` by my own build , my other script fail to found openlayers .

anyone can help me to compile correctly openlayer?

thx a lot

harksin

this is the top of my build :

```
(function (root, factory) {
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
      define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
      module.exports = factory();
  } else {
      root.ol = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {



 var OPENLAYERS = {};

  var l,aa=aa||{},ba=this;function m(b){return void 0!==b}function t(b,c,d){b=b.split(".");d=d||ba;b[0]in d||!d.execScript||d.execScript("var "+b[0]);for(var e;b.length&&  [...]
```

this is the top of official build :

```
var OpenLayers={VERSION_NUMBER:"Release 2.13.1",singleFile:!0,_getScriptLocation:function(){for(var a=/(^|(.*?\/))(OpenLayers[^\/]*?\.js)(\?|$)/,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),c,d="",e=0,f=b.length; [...]
```

Comment: Have you tried extending it using JavaScript prototype ?

Comment: You are comparing an ol3 build to an ol2 build here. ol3 and ol2 are very different beasts. Replacing ol2 by ol3 in an application requires changing that application's code.